# How to make two interfaces use same gateway in same network?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, routing, routing-table

I have two interfaces: eth0 and wlan0 what I need to use simultaneously. Every time I restart my device or networking service, route -n gives:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I have to use every time:

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
```

To get:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

How can I get ^ this by default after reboot or restarting networking?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.35/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
metric 300


interface wlan0
sttic ip_address=192.168.1.31/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
metric 200


# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.35/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use simultaneously"? This looks like Linux, and I don't recall Linux routes providing that feature the way you're showing it – only one route (lowest metric) is chosen.

Comment: For example I want to have both "ping -I eth0 something.com" and "ping -I wlan0 something.com" working. I'm manually assigning things to interfaces.

Comment: After restarting only one of them works before adding route.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP notes the issue is resolved by an OS reinstall and they do not know the root cause.

Comment: Fine for me. If I had to guess, I think I messed up dhcp clients. I tried to install few of them and I think they left some garbage after deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling the OS. I still don't know what was the issue.